# Is there any way to trick a program to writing to stdout when it expects a file?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

I'm using [Keil uVision](https://www2.keil.com/mdk5/uvision/) and I'm trying to get away from using its cancerous UI by using its [command line](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/101407/0537/Command-Line/Program-Flash-Example) for building and flashing.

I'm using its command line to build like this:

```
UV4.exe -r Blinky.uvproj -o Build_Output.txt
```

The output of the build is saved to `Build_Output.txt`. I have a wrapper script that calls UV4 then prints `Build_Output.txt` to my terminal. What I would like to do is have some way to have UV4 print directly to my terminal/stdout instead of to this file. Is there any way to trick it into doing so?

I'm running this powershell in windows terminal in Windows 10.

Comment: random thought: if the log file is not locked, your terminal program can poll the contents at intervals. obviously a workaround

Comment: Ooh thats a good idea. Might try that

Comment: What about something like `UV4.exe -r Blinky.uvproj -o temporary.txt ; cat temporary.txt ; del temporary.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use the special con file as output? Something like:

```
UV4.exe -r Blinky.uvproj -o con
```

Comment: NIce idea. You might want to try CON: as file-name tough. Windows likes a colon after device-names.

Comment: Good thought. Didn't work though, failed with message 'failed to create file "con"'